# Hiding a div using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My HTML Code:

```
<div class="input-main">
    <div class="block">
        <div class="input-quest">What is your server OS</div>
        <div class="input-resp">
            <input onClick="os_others();" type="radio" name="button2" value="Yes" <?php if(!isset($_POST['button2']) || (isset($_POST['button2']) && $_POST['button2'] == 'Yes')) echo ' checked="checked"'?> checked /><label>Others</label>   
            <input onClick="os_hpux();" type="radio" name="button2" value="No" <?php if(isset($_POST['button2']) && $_POST['button2'] == 'No')  echo ' checked="checked"';?> /><label>HP-UNIX</label>
        </div>  
        </div>  

    <div id="lunidlist" >
        <div class="block-with-text-area">
        <div class="input-quest-with-text-area">Enter your LUN IDs in Hex(one ID in one line)</div>
        <div class="input-resp-with-text-area"><span><textarea  class="textarea" id="lunids" name="lunids" type="text"><?php if(isset($_POST['lunids'])) { echo htmlentities ($_POST['lunids']); }?></textarea></span> </div>   
        </div>
    </div>


<div id="hpux-details-lunlist"style="display:none;" >
    <div class="block-no-height">
            <div class="sub_headings">Enter your vbus,target and LUN ids(one in one line)</div>
        <div class="hupux-wrap-textarea">
            <div class="hpuxleft">      
                <div class="input-quest-hpux-vbus-textarea">Vbus<br/>( 0 - F )</div>
                <div class="input-resp-hpux-vbus-textarea"><span><textarea  class="textarea" id="vbus-id-list" name="vbus-id-list" type="text"><?php if(isset($_POST['vbus-id-list'])) { echo htmlentities ($_POST['vbus-id-list']); }?></textarea></span> </div>   
                </div>      

            <div class="hpuxright">
                <div class="input-quest-hpux-lun-textarea">LUN ID(In Hex)<br/>( 0 - 7 )</div>
                <div class="input-resp-hpux-lun-textarea"><span><textarea  class="textarea" id="lun-id-list" name="lun-id-list" type="text"><?php if(isset($_POST['lun-id-list'])) { echo htmlentities ($_POST['lun-id-list']); }?></textarea></span> </div>    
            </div>

            <div class="hpuxcenter">    
                <div class="input-quest-hpux-target-textarea">Target<br/>( 0 - F )</div>
                <div class="input-resp-hpux-target-textarea"><span><textarea  class="textarea" id="target-id-list" name="target-id-list" type="text"><?php if(isset($_POST['target-id-list'])) { echo htmlentities ($_POST['target-id-list']); }?></textarea></span> </div> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    <div id="error1" style="display:none;"></div>

</div>
```

In above code, I have 3 textareas in div id `hpux-details-lunlist`. If the count of lines in these three textareas are not equal the code will give an error message `Mismatch between VBUS ID, Target ID and LUN ID Counts`. This error message is echoing to a another div `error1`

javascript:

```
function os_hpux()  {
    $('#lunids').slideUp("fast");
    $('#hpux-details-lunlist').slideDown("fast");
    document.getElementById("lunids").value=""; 
    $('#lunids').attr("disabled","disabled");
    $('#hpux-details-lunlist').removeAttr("disabled");
}

function os_others()    {
    $('#lunids').slideDown("fast");
    $('#lunids').removeAttr("disabled");
    $('#hpux-details-lunlist').slideUp("fast");
    $('#hpux-details-lunlist').attr("disabled","disabled");
    document.getElementById("vbus-id-list").value="";
    document.getElementById("lun-id-list").value="";
    document.getElementById("target-id-list").value="";
}

function fun_vcount() {
    vcount = 0;
    var lines = $("#vbus-id-list").val().split("\n");
    for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
        if (lines[i].length > 0) vcount++;
    }
}

function fun_tcount() {
    tcount = 0;
    var lines = $("#target-id-list").val().split("\n");
    for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
        if (lines[i].length > 0) tcount++;
    }
}

function fun_lcount() {
    lcount = 0;
    var lines = $("#lun-id-list").val().split("\n");
    for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
        if (lines[i].length > 0) lcount++;
    }
}

$("#vbus-id-list").keyup(function () {
    fun_vcount()
    fun_tcount()
    fun_lcount()
    var message;

    if(((vcount ==tcount) && (vcount == lcount)) || (!$("#vbus-id-list").val()) || (!$("#target-id-list").val()) || (!$("#lun-id-list").val()) || ($("#hpux-details-lunlist").attr("disabled") == "disabled")) {
        $("#error1").slideUp("fast");
    }

    else{
        message ="Mismatch between VBUS ID, Target ID and LUN ID Counts";
        $("#error1").slideDown("fast");
        document.getElementById('error1').innerHTML=message;
    }
});

$("#target-id-list").keyup(function () {
    fun_vcount()
    fun_tcount()
    fun_lcount()
    var message;
    if(((vcount ==tcount) && (vcount == lcount)) || (!$("#vbus-id-list").val()) || (!$("#target-id-list").val()) || (!$("#lun-id-list").val()) || ($("#hpux-details-lunlist").attr("disabled") == "disabled")) {
        $("#error1").slideUp("fast");
    }

    else{
        message ="Mismatch between VBUS ID, Target ID and LUN ID Counts";
        $("#error1").slideDown("fast");
        document.getElementById('error1').innerHTML=message;
    } 
});

$("#lun-id-list").keyup(function () {
    fun_vcount()
    fun_tcount()
    fun_lcount()
    var message;
    if(((vcount ==tcount) && (vcount == lcount)) || (!$("#vbus-id-list").val()) || (!$("#target-id-list").val()) || (!$("#lun-id-list").val()) || ($("#hpux-details-lunlist").attr("disabled") == "disabled")) {
        $("#error1").slideUp("fast");
    }

    else{
        message ="Mismatch between VBUS ID, Target ID and LUN ID Counts";
        $("#error1").slideDown("fast");
        document.getElementById('error1').innerHTML=message;
    }   
});
```

The issue I am facing :

I am able display the error code for the line count mismatch between textareas `vbus-id-list`, `target-id-list` and `lun-id-list`. But when when I am trying to hide these textareas using the first radio button (on selection of `os_others()`, hiding the `hpux-details-lunlist`) I am able to hide the textarea, but the error message is not hiding. It will still show the message `Mismatch between VBUS ID, Target ID and LUN ID Counts`

If you see my above code, I have included `($("#hpux-details-lunlist").attr("disabled") == "disabled"))` and if this true hiding the div `error1`. But this is not working for me. the error message keep showing there ? How can I hide that ?

Comment: Please correctly indent your code! It's hard to read.

Comment: You should indent your JS, with 2 (or 4) spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
($("#hpux-details-lunlist").attr("disabled") == "disabled"))
```

to:

```
$("#hpux-details-lunlist").prop("disabled")
```

The `.prop()` method should be used to get/set disabled instead of the `.attr()` method.

Bad: `$('#hpux-details-lunlist').attr("disabled","disabled");`

**Good:** `$('#hpux-details-lunlist').prop("disabled",true);`

Bad: `$('#lunids').removeAttr("disabled");`

**Good:** `$('#lunids').prop("disabled", false);`

There are actually a few more issues in your code that should be altered.

Source: http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Comment: It giving me error `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'prop'` on console

Comment: @acr `.prop()` was added to jQuery in version 1.6. You should be using an updated version.

Comment: I have updated the jQuery to the latest version. Now I am not getting any errors in console, but the `error1` still showing up when I select other option

Comment: I noted you have quite a few more issues - more best practice kinds of things but without an adequate code sampling which can duplicate your errors I can't help.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that it is because you use `attr` instead of `prop` :

```
if( ... || $("#hpux-details-lunlist").prop("disabled"))
```

See for example this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/5876747/1127669 and see http://api.jquery.com/prop/ for reference.